Auth0 configuration in angular 18 - AuthClientConfig has valid data, but login redirects to null host name
My application is using angular-18 in stand alone mode.
I am also using ngrx and auth0.
I have injected the authClientConfig: AuthClientConfig with proper values in APP_INITIALIZER provider.
But this.authService.loginWithRedirect() redirects to empty host name https://authorize/?client_id=&scope=openid+profile+email&response_type=code&response_mode=query&state=xxx&nonce=xxx&code_challenge=xxx&code_challenge_method=S256&auth0Client=xxx
I have a console.log before this.authService.loginWithRedirect(), console.log(this.authClientConfig.get()); and it prints valid config
{
  "domain": "dev-xxx.us.auth0.com",
  "clientId": "yyyxyyyxyyxyxyy",
  "errorPath": "/auth/access-denied",
  "authorizationParams": {
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200",
    "audience": "https://audience.com/v3/api/"
  }
}

It is supposed to redirect to dev-xxx.us.auth0.com/authorize, but why it is not taking the domain from authclientconfig ?
I have tried as follows
in app.config.ts

export function auth0ConfigFactory(): () => Promise<void> {
  const store = inject(Store);
  const authClientConfig = inject(AuthClientConfig);

  return async () => {
    // Dispatch the action to load the configuration
    store.dispatch(loadConfig());

    // Wait until the configuration is completely loaded
    await firstValueFrom(
      store.select(selectInitAuthConfigComplete).pipe(
        filter((isComplete) => isComplete === true), // Wait until configuration is complete
        take(1) // Take only the first emission of true
      )
    );

    // Once config is loaded, fetch the auth configuration
    return firstValueFrom(store.select(selectAuthConfig)).then(config => {
      console.log('config', config);
      
      if (!config) {
        throw new Error('Auth0 configuration not available after loading config');
      }
      authClientConfig.set({
        domain: config.domain,
        clientId: config.clientId,
        errorPath: '/auth/access-denied',
        authorizationParams: {
          redirect_uri: config.redirectUri,
          audience: config.audience
        },
      });
    });
  };
}


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideStore(),
    provideEffects(),
    provideEffects([ConfigEffects, AuthEffects]), // Register the effects
    provideStore({ config: configReducer, auth: authReducer }), // Register the reducer
    provideStoreDevtools({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideAuth0({
      domain: '', // Placeholder value, will be replaced by APP_INITIALIZER
      clientId: '', // Placeholder value, will be replaced by APP_INITIALIZER
    }),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: auth0ConfigFactory,
      multi: true,
    },
  ]
};

app.componenet.ts


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  user$!: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store, private authService: AuthService, private authClientConfig: AuthClientConfig) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Check if user is authenticated
    this.store.select(selectIsAuthenticated).pipe(
      take(1) // Take only the first emission to determine authentication status
    ).subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        // If the user is not authenticated, redirect to login page
        console.log(this.authClientConfig.get());
        // this.authService.loginWithRedirect();
      } else {
        // If authenticated, assign the user observable
        this.user$ = this.store.select(selectUser);
      }
    });
  }

  logout(): void {
    // Handle logout logic here
    console.log('Logout triggered');
    // You can dispatch a logout action or use a logout method from AuthService
  }
}


